# IPv4 validation using regex

Tags: jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I' am trying to validate an IPv4 address in my form with unobtrusive validation. All other validations are working fine but this one is note working.

I  defined the property model like this:

```
[RegularExpression(ipAdressRegEx, ErrorMessageResourceName = "IPInvalid", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Strings))]
public virtual String IP { get; set; }
```

And my RegEx:

```
private const string ipAdressRegEx = @"/\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b/g";
```

The generated HTML is like this:

```
    <input class="k-textbox" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Invalid IP" 
data-val-regex-pattern="/\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b/g" 
id="IP" name="IP" type="text" value="">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="IP" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

But the validation shows error invalid IP erro message, for instance, to ip="192.168.1.1".

If I put the following in the browser console:

```
"192.168.1.1".match(/\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b/g)
```

(Using the pattern passed to the input validation) it returns the IP, which is correct.

I don't understand why the unobtrusive validation doesn't work in this case...

I tried with different patterns...

Comment: My guess is that the problem is because of `/g` modifier, which is JavaScript-specific I believe. It might be the case that ASP.NET MVC validation uses some other method for matching on client-side, not the `match` method you are testing. And on server-side this modifier is not supported for sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loose the slashes and the `g` option you specify in the string.  These are JavaScript delimiters for a regular expression.  The are not needed when you pass the regular expression through the API.

```
data-val-regex-pattern="\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create Method like,

```
private boolean checkIp(String ipValue,String regex){
   return ipValue.matches(regex);
}

checkIp(yourIpValue, "^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\."
                            + "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\."
                            + "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\."
                            + "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$")
```

Answer (score 0):

As I was just thinking that generated funky html of unobtrusive validation could have some issue with the behaviour of Regex on client and server. Here's the article explaining and providing some workaround

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2013/05/08/regular-expressions-are-different-in-javascript-and-unintrusive-validation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

follow this

```js
$("#adressIP, #GatewayInp, #SubnetMask").keyup(function() {
   var input = $(this).val();
   console.log(input);
   var regex = new RegExp('(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$');
   if (regex.test(input)) {
    console.log("match");
   } else {
    console.log("nomatch");
   }
});
```

Comment: Perhaps add some explanation?

Answer (score -1):

```
function ValidateIPaddress(ipaddress)   
{  
    if (/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/.test(ipaddress))  
    {  
        return (true)  
    }  
    alert("You have entered an invalid IP address!")  
    return (false)  
}
```